# open source admin theme for twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, themes, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking for a complete and responsive admin theme for an open source project I'm planning to develop.

Is there some open source admin repository with admin themes for twitter bootstrap?

Ideally it would be something like http://websdevp.com/Endless/dashboard.html

Comment: I am fan of AdminLTE but it is worth checking AdminKit here https://usebootstrap.com/theme/adminkit

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the last few months, since I asked the question, quite a lot of free options appeared.

I'll try to list them in this community wiki:

---

**AdminLTE Dasboard and Control Panel Template**

- site: http://almsaeedstudio.com/
- live: http://almsaeedstudio.com/preview
- repo: https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE
- **repo activity: HEALTHY** (Checked 24-oct-2016)

  - Last commit (not counting merges) on 19-oct-2016 = 5 days ago (from date of check).
  - Number of forks: 4.515 (at date of check).

    ### * license: MIT

**Robust Lite : Free bootstrap admin template**

- site: https://pixinvent.com/products/robust-lite-free-bootstrap-admin-template/
- live: https://pixinvent.com/free-bootstrap-template/robust-lite/html/ltr/index.html
- repo: https://github.com/pixinvent/robust-free-bootstrap-admin-template
- **repo activity: HEALTHY** (Checked 16-june-2017)

  - Last commit - 2 month ago (from date of check).

    ### * license: MIT

**Metis**

- site: http://onokumus.com/?p=63
- live: http://demo.onokumus.com/metis/
- repo: https://github.com/onokumus/Bootstrap-Admin-Template
- **repo activity: HEALTHY** (Checked 24-oct-2016)

  - Last commit (not counting merges) on 16-sep-2016 = 1 month ago (from date of check).
  - Number of forks: 1.053 (at date of check).
- license: MIT

---

**DevOOPS**

- site: http://devoops.me/
- live: http://devoops.me/themes/devoops/
- repo: https://github.com/devoopsme/devoops
- **repo activity: OLD** (Checked 24-oct-2016)

  - Last commit (not counting merges) on 20-Nov-2015 = 11 months ago (from date of check).
  - Number of forks: 349 (at date of check).
- license: GPL v3 or MIT

---

**SB Admin**

- site: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/
- live: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/
- repo: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin
- license: MIT

---

**SB Admin 2**

- site: http://startbootstrap.com/sb-admin-v2
- live: http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin-v2/
- repo: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap/tree/master/templates/sb-admin-v2
- **repo activity: DEAD**

  - This link is `404 Page Not Found` on 24-oct-2016.
- license: apache 2

---

**Light Way Admin**

- site: http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-theme/lightway-admin
- live: http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-theme/lightway-admin/preview/index.html
- repo: ?
- license: MIT

---

**Deep Blue Admin**

- site: http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-theme/deepblue-admin
- live: http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-theme/deepblue-admin/preview/index.html
- repo: ?
- license: MIT

---

**Dark Admin**

- site: http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-theme/dark-admin
- live: http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-theme/dark-admin/preview/index.html
- repo: ?
- license: MIT

---

And here's an article that lists ten more free admin bootstrap templates:

http://dizyne.net/free-bootstrap-admin-templates/

Comment: Here are a few free ones: http://usebootstrap.com/search?k=admin

Answer (score 11):

AdminLTE is a new theme. Licensed uder the MIT license. You may check it out here:

http://almsaeedstudio.com

Comment: i have one problem with this theme postback, after you click on sub-menu it does not stay it clears out and paste the entire page and its difficult to know what menu item the user clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

an interesting article with several free options

http://www.daveismyname.com/design/free-bootstrap-admin-themes/

[this one](https://github.com/onokumus/Bootstrap-Admin-Template) looks pretty complete and is licensed under the MIT